# Switching to a View after a second level of approval

Tags: workflow, infopath, infopath-rules

I've got an InfoPath Form rule to switch the view after a form is submitted.

I've got a Workflow behind the list.

I've created a field in the InfoPath from called `Form View` with a default value of `0` and added a Form Load rule to switch to the default view if `FormView = 1`.

If the approval is rejected, then the `FormView` field is updated to `1`.

If the approval is accepted, the Workflow sends an email asking the user to fill in the fields on a second view which is then submitted for approval.

If this second view is then rejected, it sends an email with comments saying "please fill in again", but it's opening the default view.

What can I do so that the user can edit the second view if rejected?

Comment: Is the FormView view switcher working as expected?

Comment: Yes that's working like a dream. I just need the user to be able to edit the second view if it's rejected after submission.

Answer (score 0):

So the rule is, if Approved - FormView field is updating to 1. Why don't you have a rule that if Rejected, update the FormView field to 1 also?

So then whether approved or rejected, the view will open to the same second view.

Or have I missed something?